# How to port compiled android open source project on samsung galaxy tab p7300

Tags: android, porting, galaxy

I need to port compiled AOSP on samsung galaxytab gt-P7300. Can anyone help me in building AOSP for this device. and then porting steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Galaxian-Soup
It's porting for P7300 and P7310.